# Probability Higher level

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

Alice's school is planning to take some students from her class on a field trip. Alice is really excited about it. There are a total of $S$ students in her class. But due to budget constraints, the school is planning to take only $N$ students for the trip. These students will be picked randomly. And each student has equal chance of being picked.
Alice's friend circle has M students including her. Though she is excited about the field trip, she will enjoy it only if there are at least $K$ of her friends with her on the trip. She is wondering what are the chances of that happening. She needs your help. Tell her the probability that she will enjoy given that she goes on the trip.

Comment: If this is a homework problem (sounds like it) it should have the self-study tag.

Answer (score 2):

These kinds of problems are usually solved by counting the number of "good" outcomes and dividing by the number of all possible outcomes.

How many ways are there to select $N$ of the $S$ students? How many ways are there that include selecting both Alice and any $K$ of her $M-1$ friends?